# Ethereum Mist connect with local private network

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum

**System information**

```
Geth Version: 1.7.3-stable

Git Commit: 4bb3c89d44e372e6a9ab85a8be0c9345265c763a

Operating System: linux
```

**Expected behaviour**

Connect Mist with local private network

**Actual behaviour**

I type command :

```
geth --datadir ~/private_network init ~/private_network/genesis.json

geth --datadir ~/private_network --networkid 3131 --ipcpath ~/private_network/geth.ipc console 2>~/private_network/console.log
```

and I run Mist but I have an error "address already in use" even if I kill processes that uses port 30303 I have the same result

**Backtrace**

> ~/.ethereum/testnet/geth/ethash count=3
>
> INFO [12-16|12:05:37] Disk storage enabled for ethash DAGs     dir=~/.ethash                       count=2
>
> INFO [12-16|12:05:37] Initialising Ethereum protocol           versions="[63 62]" network=3
>
> INFO [12-16|12:05:37] Loaded most recent local header          number=797369 hash=81c88e…3044c5 td=587702682055345
>
> INFO [12-16|12:05:37] Loaded most recent local full block      number=0      hash=419410…ca4a2d td=1048576
>
> INFO [12-16|12:05:37] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=761870 hash=08735b…e597b9 td=571350456833753
>
> INFO [12-16|12:05:37] Loaded local transaction journal         transactions=0 dropped=0
>
> INFO [12-16|12:05:37] Upgrading chain index                    type=bloombits percentage=79
>
> INFO [12-16|12:05:37] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0
>
> INFO [12-16|12:05:37] Starting P2P networking
> Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: listen udp :30303: bind: address already in use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're connecting to the Ropsten network (network=3). You have to pass in your network id into Mist using the `--network` option and provide the path to your .ipc file using `--rpc`.

> `$ ./Mist.exe --network 3131 --rpc ~/private_network/geth.ipc`

Full command line options:

> ```
> $ ./Mist.exe --help
>
> Usage: Mist.exe --help [Mist options] [Node options]
>
> Mist options:
>   --mode, -m              App UI mode: wallet, mist.  [string] [default: "mist"]
>   --node                  Node to use: geth, eth        [string] [default: null]
>   --network               Network to connect to: main, test
>                                                         [string] [default: null]
>   --rpc                   Path to node IPC socket file OR HTTP RPC hostport (if
>                           IPC socket file then --node-ipcpath will be set with
>                           this value).                                  [string]
>   --swarmurl              URL serving the Swarm HTTP API. If null, Mist will
>                           open a local node.
>                                      [string] [default: "http://localhost:8500"]
>   --gethpath              Path to Geth executable to use instead of default.
>                                                                         [string]
>   --ethpath               Path to Eth executable to use instead of default.
>                                                                         [string]
>   --ignore-gpu-blacklist  Ignores GPU blacklist (needed for some Linux
>                           installations).                              [boolean]
>   --reset-tabs            Reset Mist tabs to their default settings.   [boolean]
>   --logfile               Logs will be written to this file in addition to the
>                           console.                                      [string]
>   --loglevel              Minimum logging threshold: info, debug, error, trace
>                           (shows all logs, including possible passwords over
>                           IPC!).                      [string] [default: "info"]
>   --syncmode              Geth synchronization mode: [fast|light|full]  [string]
>   --version, -v           Display Mist version.                        [boolean]
>   --skiptimesynccheck     Disable checks for the presence of automatic time sync
>                           on your OS.                                  [boolean]
>
> Node options:
>   -  To pass options to the underlying node (e.g. Geth) use the --node- prefix,
>      e.g. --node-datadir
>
> Options:
>   -h, --help  Show help                                                [boolean]
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Why are the arguments used with the comand geth not taken into account ? geth --datadir ~/private_network --networkid 3131 --ipcpath ~/private_network/geth.ipc

Comment: I don't think geth is your problem here. I think it's Mist not detecting that geth is already running via command line. You may be starting Mist with a different data node which is causing it to attempt to spawn another instance of geth. This would explain why the error message you're getting is that the port is already in use. Notice how you're starting geth with ~/private_network as your `datadir`, but the Mist log shows dir=~/.ethash